# error in first use android studio "URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)"

Tags: android, android-studio, code-first

i just install android studio and program give this error
URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)
please help thank you
[photo of program and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcTvg.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer after researching, some countries like Iran are sanctioned by Android Studio and should use proxies so that they can make the boycott ineffective.